# MacBook pro charging light turns green and orange after some time

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging, magsafe, charger

I have three 65 watt L type chargers. Problem is with one of my laptop (MacBook pro 13 mid 2012) during charging, charging indicator light turns green and orange after some minutes(its random time sometime after a minute or more... time is not fixed). On the other side these chargers are working fine with my other MacBooks.

Full charge taking so long above 7 hours.
Battery cycle count is between 650 to 700.
No battery warnings. 
Charging port is neat and clean. 
SMC reset done so times. 
I think my chargers are fine. then what's wrong? Please help